# Find all combinations matching certain criteria in an array in Ruby

Tags: arrays, ruby

I have the following array:

```
a = ["melon | apple", "kiwi | melon", "apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi"]
```

I want all strings of yielded by connecting the latter part (after `"|"`) of a string element and the former part (before `"|"`) of the following string element. `a.combination_with_criteria(3).to_a` should output:

```
["kiwi | melon", "melon | apple", "apple | orange"]
["pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon", "melon | apple"]
```

`a.combination(3).to_a` gives all possible combinations but in random order.

Maybe it's better to work with hashes for this purpose.

Comment: Is there a good reason for this strange data structure? It looks like you'd be better off using a `Hash` rather than an array of strings separated by `|`...

Comment: probably, that's the data I get from data vendor

Comment: Actually, in fact you'd probably be best to convert this into a [tree data structure](https://github.com/evolve75/RubyTree). At that point, this becomes (relatively) easy to come up with a generic solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `a.combination(3).to_a` gives all possible combinations but in random order.

Let's see:

```
a.combination(3).to_a
#=> [
#     ["melon | apple", "kiwi | melon", "apple | orange"],
#     ["melon | apple", "kiwi | melon", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["melon | apple", "apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["kiwi | melon", "apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi"]
#   ]
```

Apparently, it contains neither `["kiwi | melon", "melon | apple", "apple | orange"]` nor `["pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon", "melon | apple"]`.

To get those as well, you have to use [`permutation`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Array.html#method-i-permutation) instead:

```
a.permutation(3).to_a
#=> [
#     ["melon | apple", "kiwi | melon", "apple | orange"],
#     ["melon | apple", "kiwi | melon", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["melon | apple", "apple | orange", "kiwi | melon"],
#     ["melon | apple", "apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["melon | apple", "pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon"],
#     ["melon | apple", "pineapple | kiwi", "apple | orange"],
#     ["kiwi | melon", "melon | apple", "apple | orange"],      <--- here
#     ["kiwi | melon", "melon | apple", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["kiwi | melon", "apple | orange", "melon | apple"],
#     ["kiwi | melon", "apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["kiwi | melon", "pineapple | kiwi", "melon | apple"],
#     ["kiwi | melon", "pineapple | kiwi", "apple | orange"],
#     ["apple | orange", "melon | apple", "kiwi | melon"],
#     ["apple | orange", "melon | apple", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["apple | orange", "kiwi | melon", "melon | apple"],
#     ["apple | orange", "kiwi | melon", "pineapple | kiwi"],
#     ["apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi", "melon | apple"],
#     ["apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon"],
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "melon | apple", "kiwi | melon"],
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "melon | apple", "apple | orange"],
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon", "melon | apple"],    <--- here
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon", "apple | orange"],
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "apple | orange", "melon | apple"],
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "apple | orange", "kiwi | melon"]
#   ]
```

You probably know that [`select`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-select) can be used to filter out the correct elements, but how does the condition look like?

Let's take a matching pair:

```
a = 'kiwi | melon'
b = 'melon | apple'
```

We can [`split`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/String.html#method-i-split) those by `' | '` to get the parts:

```
a.split(' | ') #=> ["kiwi", "melon"]
b.split(' | ') #=> ["melon", "apple"]
```

It's a match if `a`'s last word matches `b`'s first word:

```
a.split(' | ').last == b.split(' | ').first
#=> true
```

To check this for each consecutive pair of strings in an array, we can use [`each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
['kiwi | melon', 'melon | apple', 'apple | orange'].each_cons(2) do |a, b|
  p a.split(' | ').last == b.split(' | ').first
end
```

It first passes `'kiwi | melon'` and `'melon | apple'` to the block and then `'melon | apple'` and `'apple | orange'`.

For this array, the output is:

```
true
true
```

To determine if the block returns `true` for all pairs, we can append [`all?`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-all-3F) to `each_cons`:

```
['kiwi | melon', 'melon | apple', 'apple | orange'].each_cons(2).all? do |a, b|
  a.split(' | ').last == b.split(' | ').first
end
```

And this is exactly, what we can pass to `select`:

```
a.permutation(3).select do |sub_array|
  sub_array.each_cons(2).all? do |a, b|
    a.split(' | ').last == b.split(' | ').first
  end
end
#=> [
#     ["kiwi | melon", "melon | apple", "apple | orange"],
#     ["pineapple | kiwi", "kiwi | melon", "melon | apple"]
#   ]
```

Note that this still creates a huge temporary array of all permutations and it splits the strings for each comparison, so you might want to look for a more optimized solution. But this should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work:

```
def find_chains(input)
  # Split input into usable value pairs.
  pairs = input.map { |s| s.split(" | ") }

  pairs.permutation(3).select do |ar|
    ar[0][1] == ar[1][0] && ar[1][1] == ar[2][0]
  end
end

input = ["melon | apple", "kiwi | melon", "apple | orange", "pineapple | kiwi"]

find_chains(input).each do |match|
  puts "match: " + match.map { |ar| ar.join(" | ")}.join(", ")
end

# Output:
#
# match: kiwi | melon, melon | apple, apple | orange
# match: pineapple | kiwi, kiwi | melon, melon | apple
```